# What does Action mean in play framework (Scala)?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to Play Framework and was trying to understand `SimpleRouter` class. In the Play documentation, I see a simple example as:

```
val router = Router.from {
  case GET(p"/hello/$to") =>
    Action {
      Results.Ok(s"Hello $to")
    }
}
```

But I am not sure what is `Action` and what is its significance? I see it heavily used in all other routing methods as well. Here's the link to the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaSirdRouter
[image]

My reference code:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.routing.Router._
import play.api.routing._
import play.api.routing.sird._


class CacheRouter extends SimpleRouter {



  override def routes: Routes = {
    case GET(p"/") =>
      Action {
        Results.Ok(s"Hello")
      }

//    case POST(p"/") =>
//      controller.process
//
//    case GET(p"/$id") =>
//      controller.show(id)
  }

}
```

Comment: Please, do not paste code as screenshot

Comment: Hey, sorry! I added the code next to it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Action according to the Play documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaActions) is

> basically a (play.api.mvc.Request => play.api.mvc.Result) function that handles a request and generates a result to be sent to the client.

In other words, an Action a full implementation of the server side of the http request that is able to take a `play.api.mvc.Request` and do some work and return a `play.api.mvc.Result`

In your example the Action is one that does not use anything from the request and returns a static HTTP 200 response with the content `hello`

**Edit:** From the comment here it looks like you are having an issue with the `Action` in the code sample not being resolved.
The reason for this is that that is not actually a reference to the `play.api.mvc.Action` but a helper method to construct Actions.

This helper method is defined in `play.api.mbc.AbstractController` which you can extend to make use of it.

An example of this would be something like:

```scala
  class CacheRouter @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) with SimpleRouter {
    override def routes: Routes = {
      case GET(p"/") =>
        Action {
          Results.Ok(s"Hello")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Bear in mind the above is using Plays `guice` integration for dependency injection but that is just one of many options available.

Comment: hmm I see... but when I try to use it, the compiler complains saying Cannot resolve symbol Action. Even though I have done `import play.api.mvc._`

Comment: Ah, so in the sample code you have now, that `Action` that is not resolved is not the Action type from `play.api.mvc` but instead a (in my opinion confusingly named) helper function.

You can get access to that helper function by extending `play.api.mbc.AbstractController`

I'll update my answer with how to do this